# What's the difference between Accessor<SomeType> and just SomeType in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, frontend, type-conversion, solid-js

I'm doing a todo list app in Typescript using Solid. I defined a `Todo` type as follows:

```
type Todo = {
  text: string;
  complete: boolean;
};
```

And later I want to check if all the things to do in the day are done so I can increment my streak. For this I'm using local storage:

```
const [state, setState] = createStore<{days: number, todos: Todo[]}>({
  days: 0,
  todos: todos,
});
```

But then TS says something is wrong in the last `todos`: *Type 'Accessor<Todo[]>' is not assignable to type 'Todo[]'.*

So, my question is, what's the difference between my `Todo[]` and this other `Accessor<Todo[]>`? Where this Accessor comes from? Can/Should I convert it somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessor is a function that returns the stored value in a signal.

```js
type Accessor<T> = () => T;
```

Unlike React, Solid do not use virtual DOM and does not re-render upon state update. So it needs function calls to get the value of a signal. That is how Solid achieves reactivity.

The `createSignal` function returns an array with `[Accessor<T>, Setter<T>]`.

```js
const [item, setItem] = createSignal(10);
        ^
//    This is an Accessor<T>

// To get the stored value, you need to invoke the accessor
console.log(item());
```

The `createStore` uses a signal internally and it returns an array with an accessor and a setter. But its accessor uses a proxy object which delegates its property access to the internal signal.

```js
const [todos, setTodos] = createStore([]);
        ^
//    This is a proxied object, not a plain value T
```

Since only objects and array supports Proxy API, you can only use an object or an array with `createStore` function.

The exported type signature of the `createStore` function is not derived but manually typed to suppress complications:

```js
function createStore<T extends object = {}>(...[store, options]: {} extends T ? [store?: T | Store<T>, options?: {
    name?: string;
}] : [store: T | Store<T>, options?: {
    name?: string;
}]): [get: Store<T>, set: SetStoreFunction<T>];
```

It seems you are trying to store a signal in a store that is how you get that warning but a store value itself is reactive and implements all the necessary API to insert, delete and update items. Avoid storing signals because you would be introducing totally unnecessary abtraction layer.